# Elixir remote pubsub

Tags: elixir, publish-subscribe

I'm learning Elixir and one of the things I would like to implement is a simple pubsub, where the publisher and consumer reside in different nodes, for now without the use of tooling like Redis.

What I am trying at the moment is do it without phoenix. I've looked at a few options, one of them was the new Registry, but it seams that it doesn't work remotely.

The other option I tried was gproc. Node.list() shows me my nodes, so the cluster seams to be ok, but `:gproc.send({:p, :l, :event_manager}, {:message, "stuff"})` still only works within one node.

My question is this: is there any standard way of doing pubsub with Elixir I must have missed?

Comment: I have not used `:gproc` so I can't comment what your missing. Have you looked at the various pubsub packages on `hex.pm`? Also `phoenix_pubsub` does not have any dependencies on `phoenix`, so my might be able to use it without the rest of phoenix.

Comment: I have tried some, yes. About to try phoenix_pubsub and Pg2PubSub.

Comment: Let us know how it goes

Comment: I just did a quick and simple implementation based on :pg2. I basically start same group both on the publisher and consumer apps, on the consumer I join the group I would like consume in, then I just send a message from the producer to all nodes which have joined that group.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [GenStage](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage)? It's built on top of GenServer, and it should work across nodes in a cluster.

There's an example of a producer to producer/consumer to consumer chain [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples/producer_consumer.exs), and you could modify that example to be a simple producer to consumer.

There are various dispatchers as well, like the [GenStage.BroadcastDispatcher](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.BroadcastDispatcher.html#content), if you need multiple consumers subscribed to the same types of messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple answer is because

```
{:p, :l, :event_manager}
```

should be

```
{:p, :g, :event_manager}
```

The `:l` means `local` and `:g` means `:global`.

But, I would just suggest using `phoenix_pubsub` because it is extremely well written for a distributed pubsub system. `gproc` is a bit more complicated than just a `pubsub` system.

Also, `phoenix_pubsub` does something really clever by having only one `process` on each `node` handling their own local `ets` distribution table and those processes just talk to each other to achieve distribution.

Comment: I missed the :g vs :l. Thanks for pointing that out. I will take another look at `phoenix_pubsub`